# Order by and Paginate in polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have three tables: `posts`, `comments` and `scores`

`comments` table:

```
 id | body | user_id | commentable_type | commentable_id | created_at
```

`scores` table:

```
 id | score | user_id | scoreable_type | scoreable_id | created_at
```

i want to get comments for a specific post but these comments should be ordered by their score(vote)!

By now i have this code but comments are not sorted by their score!

```
$limit = 2;
$post = Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) use ($limit) {
    $query->paginate($limit);
}])->find(3);
return $post;
```

**EDIT:**
and in my `Comment` model class i have:

```
public function scores() {
    return $this->morphMany(Score::class, 'scoreable');
  }
```

I can get all comments and then sort them in collection but it's waste of resources...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried joining scores to comments and ordering by score?

Comment: @chasenyc oh,not yet...can your provide an example?

Comment: Do you want only 2 records of comments table?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `orderBy` to query inside the callback, this way:

```
$limit = 2;

$post = Post::with([
    'comments.score' => function ($query){
        $query->orderBy('score', 'DESC');
    }, 
    'comments' => function ($query) use ($limit) {
        $query->take($limit);
    }
])->find(3);

return $post;
```

Comment: i take scores of each comment from scores table which has a polymorphic relation, your code doesn't work because comments table doesn't have a score column!

Comment: @AliSherafat take a look of my edit and do you want to retrieve only 2 comments per post?

Comment: limit count is not important by now, By the way it can be a number between 10-20

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = 2;
$post = Post::with(['comments.scores' => function ($query) use ($limit) {
    $query->orderBy('score', 'DESC');->paginate($limit);
}])->find(3);
return $post;
```

Comment: @JoseRojas have a look at my EDIT in question!

Comment: no, i have to order by sum(score) because each comment can have lot's of scores record in scores table (polymorphic relation) and orderby sum(score) not working and i don't know what to do!